# C# Search array within provided index points

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, indexing

I'm not sure how best to phrase this. I have a text file of almost 80,000 words which I have converted across to a string array.

Basically I want a method where I pass it a word and it checks if it's in the word string array. To save it searching 80,000 each time I have indexed the locations where the words beginning with each letter start and end in a two dimensional array. So wordIndex[0,0] = 0 when the 'A' words start and wordIndex[1,0] = 4407 is where they end. Then wordIndex[0,1] = 4408 which is where the words beginning with 'B' start etc.

What I would like to know is how can I present this range to a method to have it search for a value. I know I can give an index and length but is this the only way? Can I say look for x within range y and z?

Comment: I would create a method you call to search for the word, this would find the indexes into that 2d-array and grab the indexes to the word array out of it. Then I would pass the word + the indexes to a method that would do a binary search for the word. If you pass inn 'STACK' as a word, I would grab the index for 'ST' from your array as well as for 'SU' (S + next letter after T), then search in that range using binary search.

Comment: Having said that there are already existing data structures in .NET like a Dictionary or a HashSet that can be used to good effect for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you could use a `for` loop to search just a part of the array:

```
string word = "apple";
int start = 0;
int end = 4407;
bool found = false;

for (int i = start; i <= end ; i++)
{
    if (arrayOfWords[i] == word)
    {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

But since the description of your index implies that your array is already sorted a better way might be to go with [Array.BinarySearch<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cy9f6wb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Aha, yes of course, I was too busy thinking there was a shortcut and didn't stop to think I could just loop it. This might be the quick and dirty solution for me. Was just hoping for some elegant method. Many thanks. :)

Answer (score 3):

Look at [Trie set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). It can help you to store many words using few memory and quick search. [Here](https://github.com/mkozhevnikov/autocomplete/blob/master/Engine/Storage/TrieStorage.cs) is good implementation.

Comment: I think I might be getting a bit ahead of myself if I looked into these. It's definitely something I will consider in the future though.

Comment: @LJSpring be brave :) it' very good data structure and has "easy" implementation. if you need some help - just ask

Comment: Thanks Backs :) Just don't want to move quicker than the material provided by the lecturer at the moment. Might surprise him with this at some point though!